# What are the criteria for the new mark on files in a library?

Tags: library

How long do people see the "new mark" in a library on files? Or which criteria must be fullfilled that this mark will disappear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default setting for SharePoint 2013 is two days, which you can check using this script:

```
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://portal
$WebApp.DaysToShowNewIndicator
2
```

You can change the number of days the same way:

```
$WebApp.DaysToShowNewIndicator = 5
$WebApp.DaysToShowNewIndicator
5
```

Reference: [NEW INDICATOR IN SHAREPOINT LISTS AND LIBRARIES – NUMBER OF DAYS TO SHOW](https://danmyhre.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/new-indicator-in-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-number-of-days-to-show/)

Answer (score 1):

The !New icon will show by default for 2 days after the item is added. It can be modified to be longer or sorter.

```
stsadm.exe -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv [number_of_days] -url [servername]
```

http://sympmarc.com/2008/08/05/new-item-icon/